# How to redistribute VC9 libraries with PHP 5.3 windows binaries

Tags: php, windows, runtime, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++

I am in a process of including the VC9 runtime libraries with PHP 5.3.6 windows binaries. This would avoid the end user to download vcredist_x86.exe and install it in every machine.

There is a folder PHP where php binaries are residing. So from which location can I get the VC9 libraries and where should I place it?

I had tried copying the folders from winsxs to my PHP folder, but it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the redist install package together with your installer.

You can perform a silent install of this package in your own installation script.

Comment: Yes. I accept it is a good option. But I prefer including the dlls in the folder than doing the installation, because the end user machine might not have admin previlages.